# Correct way to convert a string to the proper type for an NDB property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

If I have some (string) values from a GET or POST request with the associated `Property` instances, one `IntegerProperty` and one `TextProperty`, say, is there a way to convert the values to the proper (user) types without a long tedious chain of `isinstance` calls?

I'm looking to reproduce this sort of functionality (all input validation omitted for clarity):

```
for key, value in self.request.POST.iteritems():
    prop = MyModel._properties[key]

    if isinstance(prop, ndb.IntegerProperty):
        value = int(value)
    elif isinstance(prop, (ndb.TextProperty, ndb.StringProperty)):
        pass # it's already the right type
    elif ...
    else
        raise RuntimeError("I don't know how to deal with this property: {}"
                           .format(prop))

    setattr(mymodelinstance, key, value)
```

For example, if there is a way to get the `int` class from an `IntegerProperty` and the `bool` class from a `BooleanProperty` etc., that would do the job.

The ndb metadata API doesn't really solve this elegantly, as far as I can see; with `get_representations_of_kind` I can reduce the number of cases, though.

Comment: I can feel your pain... one question though, you should have known the expected data types from the **POST** items, so why not just get the **values** by expected **keys** and convert them to the appropriate type?

Comment: @Anzel Not sure what you mean about knowing the expected data types from the POST items. In the model definition I have 45 properties of a few different types; in the interest of Don't Repeat Yourself I'd like to not repeat the mapping between property names and types anywhere but still know whether a value like "True" or "5" needs to be interpreted as a bool, string, or int.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but since the data you are going to CONVERT are either in GET/POST data, you can define a conversion function to map the key/value pair...

Comment: `Porperty` class has `_get_base_value(self, entity)` method which may help. [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `dict` to map between user-defined types to built-in types by using `type` of the object as a key and a built-in type as value.

F.e.

```
class IntegerProperty(int):
    pass

class StringProperty(str):
    pass

a, b  = IntegerProperty('1'), StringProperty('string')

def to_primitive(obj):
    switch = {IntegerProperty: int, StringProperty: str}
    return switch[type(obj)](obj)

for x in (a, b):
        print(to_primitive(x))
```

Because here the key is type of the object instead of `isinstance` check, if more than one user-defined types map to a single built-in type `KeyError` will arise if the type is not in the `dict`. So you have to explicitly add every user-defined type to the switch `dict`.

F.e.

```
class TextProperty(StringProperty):
    pass
switch = {IntegerProperty: int, StringProperty: str, TextProperty: str}
```

Above we have added the new `TextProperty` to the `switch` even though `TextProperty` is subclass of `StringProperty`. If you don't want to do that we have to get the key from `isinstance` check.
Here's how to do it;

```
class IntegerProperty(int):
    pass

class StringProperty(str):
    pass

class TextProperty(StringProperty):
    pass

a, b, c = IntegerProperty('1'), StringProperty('string'), TextProperty('text')

def to_primitive(obj):
    switch = {IntegerProperty: int, StringProperty: str}
    key = filter(lambda cls: isinstance(obj, cls), switch.keys())
    if not key:
        raise TypeError('Unknown type: {}'.format(repr(obj)))
    key = key[0]

    return switch[key](obj)

for x in (a, b, c):
        print(to_primitive(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python package called [WTForms](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms) that is enormously helpful for this, and generally makes form processing a much more pleasant experience.

Here is a really simple example:

```
class MyForm(wt.Form):
    text = MyTextAreaField("Enter text")
    n = wt.IntegerField("A number")

f = MyForm(self.request.POST)
f.validate()
print f.text.data
print f.n.data
```

Calling `f.validate()` will automatically convert the POST data to the data type specified by the form.  So `f.text.data` will be a string and `f.n.data` will be an int.

It also gracefully handles invalid data.  If a user inputs a letter for the integer field, then `f.n.data` will be `None`.  You can also specify error messages that are easily incorporated into your web page.

WTForms takes a huge amount of drudgery out of form processing!